# Can not load spatial data from MSSQL on Linux

Tags: r, rgdal, sql-server-spatial

I have a table on the MS SQL server. I am trying to import the data in R using the `rgdal` package. I can import the table on Windows without any problems using the following code:

```
readOGR(dsn = "MSSQL:server=NAME.domain.com;
                     database=Spatial;
                     trusted_connection=Yes",
        layer = "Apkaimes",
        encoding = "UTF-8", use_iconv = T)
```

However, I am not able to read the same table from the same SQL server on Linux. I am using the following code where the driver is specified:

```
readOGR(dsn = "MSSQL:server=NAME.domain.com;
                     database=Spatial;
                     driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
                     trusted_connection=Yes",
        layer = "Apkaimes")
```

I am getting the `no features found` error. However, I am able to connect to the server and to list the layers with the `ogrListLayers()`. I tried different combinations and values for the `encoding` and `use_iconv` with out success.

The `ogrInfo()` produce different results:

On Windows:

```
Source: "MSSQL:server=NAME.domain.com;
                     database=Spatial;
                     trusted_connection=Yes", layer: "Apkaimes"
Driver: MSSQLSpatial; number of rows: 85 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Extent: (495970 301544.7) - (587883.1 380104.2)
CRS: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-6000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
Number of fields: 2 
  name type length typeName
1 Code    4      7   String
2 Name    4     20   String
```

On Linux:

```
Source: "MSSQL:server=NAME.domain.com;
                     database=Spatial;
                     driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
                     trusted_connection=Yes", layer: "Apkaimes"
Driver: MSSQLSpatial, no features found
CRS: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-6000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs  
Number of fields: 3 
  name type length typeName
1   ID    0     10  Integer
2 Code    4      7   String
3 Name    4     20   String
```

Obviously rows are not imported on Linux.

SQL collation is `Latvian_CI_AS` if this helps.

GDAL version:

```
> system("gdalinfo --version")
GDAL 2.3.0, released 2018/05/04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but probably the GDAL version was too old. I can successfully load spatial data from MSSQL on CentOS 8 with GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28.

Working code example.

```
options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings" = "none")
require(rgdal)

system("gdalinfo --version")

tab <- ogrDrivers()
tab[grep("MSSQL", tab$name), ]

dsn <- "MSSQL:server=NAME.server.com;
              database=Spatial;
              driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
              trusted_connection=Yes"

ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = "Apkaimes", encoding = "UTF-8", use_iconv = T)

dat <- readOGR(dsn = dsn, layer = "Apkaimes", encoding = "UTF-8", use_iconv = T)

head(dat@data)

dat@bbox
```